# How to add a revit DB built-in-category list to a listbox on a form

Tags: c#, listbox, element, categories, revit

If I try to use addrange to add this list "`builtInCats_List = new List<BuiltInCategory>();`,"
to a list box I get the following error below.

> cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'

How can I populate the listbox on a form with the revit.db list of element category types?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like addrange needs an array to work.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Do you have a collection of Elements that are of a specific builtInCategory?
If so, convert your list items to an element array[] and try again. 
For example, if you looking to add 'Walls' to the listbox using addrange:

```
 Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element[] Walls = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).ToElements().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your List to an Array:

```
yourListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(builtInCats_List.ToArray());
```

Comment: it still is an implicit conversion

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code populate the listbox, I found this by skimming through the building coder site. Thanx for your assistance.

lstb1.DataSource = builtInCats_List;
lstb1.DisplayMember = "Name";